# Change of default vnc port fails (?)

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop

I have edited `/usr/bin/vncserver` so that the line defining base port number is as follows:

`$vncPort = 3388 + $displayNumber;`

Then: `vncserver :1`

My nmap shows among others:

```
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

On the other hand:

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep 3389

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14311/Xtightvnc
```

1. Why vnc seems to be still listening on `5900`?
2. What is `ms-wbt-server`?
3. After the changes I made, shoulnd't I have `vnc` on `3389`?

My end purpose is to map vnc to remote desktop default port `3389`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it also modifying line 543 of `vncserver` (sub CheckDisplayNumber) to read like:

```
if (!bind(S, pack('S n x12', $AF_INET, 3388 + $n))) {
```

It is the procedure that checks if the requested port is free or not.